# Pequeño espacio entre <img> y <div> que la contiene

Tags: html, css

¡Hola!

Verán. Tengo un pequeño problema con el cual aún no doy solución.

Tengo contenida una imagen (<img>) dentro de un <div>, de esta manera:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img id="preview-tileset">
</div>
```

Y el estilo es éste:

```
.image-container {
    border:1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 1200px;
    max-height:600px;

    overflow: auto;

    background: url(media/transparency.png);
}
.image-container, .image-container img {
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

La imagen no tiene ningún estilo además del mostrado en el código anterior. Sin embargo, la imagen queda con un pequeño margen dentro del div, haciendo que se vea así:

[image]

Queda un pequeño espacio de unos cuantos pixeles de margen. La imagen no tiene dicho espacio vacío, y no hay ningún otro elemento de por medio.

¿Qué puede estar causando este problema?

Si falta algo de información, por favor coméntenmelo y con gusto la daré.

Gracias de antemano, :).

Comment: Mira en el inspector del navegador, quizá exista algún estilo que dé vida a ese espacio.

Comment: @JordiHuertas
Ya lo hice y ningún elemento producía el espacio. Solucioné el problema agregando la propiedad `float:left` a la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es que tu imagen se ajuste al mismo tamaño del div contenedor lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
.image-container{ 
    position:relative; 
    display:block; 
    width:1200px; 
    height:600px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
} 

.container-image img{ 
     position:absolute; 
     top:0px; 
     witdh:100%; 
     height:100%; 
}
```

Comment: Coloca el codigo como texto, no como imagem.

Comment: No, no. Todo lo contrario. No necesito que la imagen se ajuste, sino que quede en su tamaño original y el div permita _"hacer scroll"_ para ver sólo una parte de ésta (como se ve en [este gif](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n21nb62evprt3jt/GIF10.gif?dl=0)). Sin embargo, y también se puede apreciar en las imágenes que he dejado, queda un pequeño espacio en la parte inferior del div.

Comment: No compartas codigo como imagen, sino como texto ya que es más fácil probarlo. Tu puedes editar la pregunta las veces que quieres .

Comment: Antes de intentar ayudar a alguien, deberías leer [¿Cómo escribir una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para conocer la forma de responder al OP y completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer el funcionamiento correcto de esta comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Las imagenes son inline por defecto, la ñapa de ponerle float es una mala practica, para evitar ese espacio simplemente ponle esto:

`img#preview-tileset{display:block}`

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola de nuevo! Estuve como un tonto añadiendo y quitando propiedades a todos los elementos del sitio desde la consola, hasta que di con una que me funcionó. Se trata de añadir un float a la imagen:

```
#preview-tileset {float: left}
```

Y de esta manera ese margen tan molesto ha desaparecido. Me sabe un tanto mal que la solución fuera tan "corta", pero cuando no se sabe pues pasa lo que pasa xD.

Siento las molestias, tema solucionado.